# Why is Nginx showing a 404 page when typing the domain?

Tags: nginx

I am trying to host multiple domains under one droplet (digitalocean) so under one IP address. My main domain is mikolaj.dk, and it works. However, I wanted to add coingo.dk, and so I added `coingo.dk www.coingo.dk` under `server_name` block. But when I just type coingo.dk in the URL, nginx shows a 404 error page. When I prefix it with `www`, it works. When I type https://coingo.dk or https://www.coingo.dk, it also works. But I can't expect visitors to type in www or https in front of the url. What am I doing wrong? My server block is as follows:

```
server {
    server_name coingo.dk www.coingo.dk;
    root /var/www/coingo/public/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on /var/run/php7.2-fpm.sock
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `curl` you can see that both domains return a 404 status when accessed using `http`, so that fact that one appears to work for you is probably related to your browser cache. It's not clear from your question where you are terminating SSL and serving the `https` version of the site.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
There was some problem with a pre-existing letsencrypt certificate.
Now it works,
thanks